# Get all attribute values from XML

Tags: xml, xmllint

I have the following XML sample file.

```
<root>
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="id1">some</li>
    <li id="id2"> unimportant
        </li>
    <li id="id3"> text.
        </li>
</ul>

<ul id="tag">
    <li id="id1">SOME</li>
    <li id="id2"> MORE
        </li>
    <li id="id3"> TEXT.
        </li>
</ul>
</root>
```

I would like to use `xmllint` to extract all attribute values of all `<li>` elements which are listed under `<ul id="nav">`.

I can use

```
xmllint --xpath '//ul[@id="nav"]/li/@id' sample.xml
```

which will return

```
id="id1" id="id2" id="id3"
```

However, I would like to get

```
id1 id2 id3
```

I tried

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//ul[@id="nav"]/li/@id)' sample.xml
```

but this only return the value of the first attribute

```
id1
```

Can I extract all values without resorting to other tools like awk, sed etc.? They may be delimited by either space or newline, it does not really matter in my case.

Comment: Can you use xmlstarlet?

Comment: @DanielHaley Yes, I have xmlstarlet on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use xmlstarlet, you can use the `-v` (`--value-of`) command line option:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//ul[@id='nav']/li/@id" sample.xml
```

I don't think you can use HTML as an input for the `sel` command, but I could be wrong.

I know you can with the `tr` (translate) command though (with `--html`). Then you could use an XSLT...

```
xmlstarlet tr --html sample.xsl sample.xml
```

**XSLT** (sample.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//ul[@id='nav']/li/@id">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works nicely for the sample file. However, I am using this to extract data from html files. `xmlstarlet` fails to extract the data from html files. It gives several errors about a malformed document. `xmllint` has the `--html` option which will also print out errors about malformed input file but will still extract data. Is there some similiar option for `xmlstarlet`?

Comment: @nautical - Please see my edit. (I rarely use xmlstarlet or xmllint, so I could be wrong about not being able to use HTML as input to `sel`.)

Comment: I tried the `--html` with `sel` but it made no difference for HTML input. The XSL sample still complained about malformed HTML but it still solved it quite nicely. Thanks.